# Identity Server 4 forced logout users

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have setup an IdentityServer4 application with .net core 1.1 version. I have a requirement where an Admin user can deactivate users in the system. After deactivating, those users should not be able to use the system. They should be forced SignOut from all the browsers and devices.

*Note: Application is configured to use oAuth and OpenId.*

What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: I think what you need is documented here?: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signout.html

Comment: @Arwin for version 1 it is documented here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore1/topics/signout.html

Answer (score 1):

The best option for your requirements is to switch to reference tokens with server-side validation, as described in [the docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore1/topics/reference_tokens.html). It is not the basic OpenId Connect protocol, but it provides server-side control over token validity.

Answer (score 0):

**OpenId Asp.net identity**

If you are using Asp.net identity as you have tagged.  You can go into the database and change the users SecurityStamp on the AspNetUsers. This will cause the user to be logged out of the system the next time it is validated.   By default i believe its validated every thirty minutes but this is something you can configure yourself.

To lock them out you can set the LockoutEnd to sometime in the distant future. Locked out users will not be able to login until the time has expired.  This column is also on the on the AspNetUsers table.

**Oauth2**

Remember locking out a user is probably not going to effect any access tokens or refresh tokens that may have been granted to clients the user has granted access to.  So as for Oauth things will be a little more complicated.

Access tokens granted to clients for this user will continue to work until they have expired unless you are testing that the user has been locked out even when your api is validating the access token.  So if you want to do this then your going to have to add that into the validation of your application / API.

Refresh tokens I believe are stored in the PersistedGrants table in the identity server. This is not something i have dug into much its just a hint. Old refresh tokens will probably still work but i would think you could add something into the identity server to ensure that this user has not been locked out before returning an access token.

Comment: Refresh tokens are by default set to one time use, causing 'old' refresh tokens to be invalidated the moment a new refresh token is issued. Like reference tokens they can be [revoked](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/revocation.html).

Comment: So a user can only have an application installed once?   (by default)

Comment: No I mean the refresh token is only valid for one time use. When the refresh token is used (in order to request an access token) two tokens are returned, the access token and a new refresh token. So you can never use the refresh token twice.